# In a Visual Studio 2010 Database Project, how do I make a specified user the owner of a Schema?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dbproj

As the title says, I have a user defined in my DB project that needs to be setup so that it is the owner of a specific Schema. How do I define that in the DB project?

I need to modify the creation of the Schema so that it looks like: 
CREATE SCHEMA <> AUTHORIZATION <>
CREATE ROLE <> AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

But I'm not sure where exactly it goes.